# how to authenticate docker build when using private gitlab repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When running docker build on my Dockerfile, I pull the most up to date code from a private gitlab repo using a FROM gitlab statment. I am getting a access forbidden error as I have not given my credentials. How do you give your credentials so that I can pull from this private repo?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are talking about [Gitlab Container Registry](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/))

To be able to pull docker images from private registries, you need to first run this at the command line:

```
$ docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
```

If you are running this in a CI environment, you should set these as secret environment variables.

With Gitlab, I believe it is something along these lines:

```
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.example.com
```

See the above linked page (search for "login") to see more examples and instructions.